# How to handle a UID of an ics calednar that will change every time I access it?

Tags: php, icalendar, uid

I want to insert a memo on an Airbnb calendar on my PHP program.
I wrote a program to get and synchronize iCal data of Airbnb in PHP.

```
<?php
$ical_url = 'https://www.airbnb.it/calendar/ical/2533404.ics?s=580a83c1bcbc0e8af72cfc62bcc2676d';
$ctx = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
'method' => 'GET',
'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko')
)
);
$ical = file_get_contents($ical_url,false,$ctx);
echo '<pre>'.$ical.'</pre>';
```

I can get the data of ical, but UID which is included in the event change every time I want to access.

This is the sample.

1.first access

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//Airbnb Inc//Hosting Calendar 0.8.8//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150709
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150708
UID:4q8n18b59vlt--a9biqyf1iwqq@airbnb.com
DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08-07-2015\nCHECKOUT: 09-07-2015\nNIGHTS: 1\nPHONE: 
 \nEMAIL: (nessun indirizzo email alias disponibile)\nPROPERTY: CASA MANI
: Castellabate dal mare\n
SUMMARY:Marco Marcigliano (4PPN2S)
LOCATION:CASA MANI: Castellabate dal mare
END:VEVENT
```

2.second access

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//Airbnb Inc//Hosting Calendar 0.8.8//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150709
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150708
UID:-q0wzyk0t5hkw-7gujduyluxdt@airbnb.com
DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08-07-2015\nCHECKOUT: 09-07-2015\nNIGHTS: 1\nPHONE: 
\nEMAIL: (nessun indirizzo email alias disponibile)\nPROPERTY: CASA MANI
: Castellabate dal mare\n
SUMMARY:Marco Marcigliano (4PPN2S)
LOCATION:CASA MANI: Castellabate dal mare
END:VEVENT
```

So I can't put memo to airbnb event.

Can I get iCal data without changing the UID?
Or is there unique ID in addition to UID?

Comment: We are also facing the same problem. Trying to import from Airbnb calendars & everytime it gives a different UID when it's accessed. This is causing the events to be re-imported as our duplication check is based on the UID field for Google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that this is an airbnb issue and not a google calendar issue.

Other iCal accommodation providers (eg homeaway.com) give consistent unique uids.

Exporting a google calender (calendar.google.com) twice also gives consistent unique uids.

The workaround i implemented was to use the airbnb booking ref from the summary -

```
SUMMARY:Marco Marcigliano (4PPN2S)
```

and ignore their uid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we received on 30 July 2016 from Airbnb support regarding the above issue:

> The issue you are experiencing does indeed sound quite frustrating.
> I'm afraid though, that there is no clear solution I can offer. The
> issue appears to be with the Google calendar and how it is interacting
> with the Airbnb calendar.
>
> I must reiterate that third party websites are not designed with our
> calendar in mind. If after following the steps to export the Airbnb
> calendar, you are encountering difficulties, there is little we can
> do.
>
> Perhaps this is an issue which google need to resolve, and maybe this
> is something Airbnb should look into also. I'm going to pass on the
> information you have given to me and I'm sure the feedback will be
> taken seriously.
>
> For now, I'm very sorry that I can't give you any concrete solution,
> but I will pass on this issue as something which needs to be
> investigated. Hopefully sometime in the future these problems will be
> dealt with.
>
> Again, my sincerest apologies. If there is anything else I can do, do
> not hesitate to ask.

There doesn't seem to be a solution for this problem unless Airbnb take this feedback & works on making their 'uid' unique.